# Strange build error when using Objective-C framework file in Swift project (Empatica)

Tags: ios

I've been following [this tutorial](http://developer.empatica.com/ios-sdk-tutorial-072.html) to use the Empatica SDK framework (written in Objective-C) in my Swift project.

Here's what I did:

1. I dragged the Objective-C .framework file onto my Swift project
2. I created the bridging file to use Objective-C in Swift
3. Everything worked well (ie I was able to get Swift to detect Objective-C code); however, all of this work still resulted in the following build error that I cannot seem to understand:

**EDIT:**
The "_OBJ_CASS" error is resolved, but now I'm only have the following error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you able to integrate Empatica framework in swift? I am getting strange error /EmpaLink-ios-0.7-full.framework/Headers/EmpaticaAPI-0.7.h:4:13: 'IOBluetooth/IOBluetooth.h' file not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Brigding Header File to access that here is example [link](http://ethandrower.com/?p=366)

And Try this one also Go to Build setting And Enable Bitcode Yes And it works Dude.

Comment: Go to Build setting And Enable Bitcode Yes And it works Dude.

Comment: U try this? it is worked sorry i didn't see your error image try this it is workd bro dont worry.